# Selectively set values in numpy array (or set on condition)

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

```
a = np.array([[0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 0], [0, 0, 10, 11], [0, 0, 1, 7]])
array([[ 0,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  3,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  7]])
```

There are `0` entries in each row. I need to assign a value to each of these zero entries, where the value is calculated as follows:

```
V = 0.1 * Si / Ni

where Si is the sum of row i
      Ni is the number of zero entries in row i
```

I can calculate Si and Ni fairly easy:

```
S = np.sum(a, axis=1)
array([ 2,  4, 21,  8])

N = np.count_nonzero(a == 0, axis=1)
array([3, 2, 2, 2])
```

Now, `V` is calculated as:

```
V = 0.1 * S/N
array([0.06666667, 0.2       , 1.05      , 0.4       ])
```

But how do I assign V[i] to a *zero* entry in *i*-th row? So I'm expecting to get the following array `a`:

```
array([[ 0.06666667,  2,  0.06666667,  0.06666667],
       [ 0.2,  1,  3,  0.2],
       [ 1.05,  1.05, 10, 11],
       [ 0.4,  0.4,  1,  7]])
```

I need some kind of selective broadcasting operation or assignment?

Comment: Use `numpy.where` with broadcasting: `np.where(a == 0, V[:, None], a)`

Comment: @user3483203, thanks! What does `V[:, None]` do? I understand that `V[:]` is a slicing that takes the whole array, but what is with `None` ?

Comment: You want to assign row-wise, not column wise, so broadcasting allows `V` to broadcast against the right rows of `a` when assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.where

`np.where(a == 0, v.reshape(-1, 1), a)`

```
array([[ 0.06666667,  2.        ,  0.06666667,  0.06666667],
       [ 0.2       ,  1.        ,  3.        ,  0.2       ],
       [ 1.05      ,  1.05      , 10.        , 11.        ],
       [ 0.4       ,  0.4       ,  1.        ,  7.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `np.where`:

```
z = a == 0
np.where(z, (0.1*a.sum(1)/z.sum(1))[:,None], a)

array([[ 0.06666667,  2.        ,  0.06666667,  0.06666667],
       [ 0.2       ,  1.        ,  3.        ,  0.2       ],
       [ 1.05      ,  1.05      , 10.        , 11.        ],
       [ 0.4       ,  0.4       ,  1.        ,  7.        ]])
```

Comment: thanks for feedback! I have not seen `z = a == 0` kind of constructs before, very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a mask:

```
for i in range(V.size):
    print((a[i,:] == 0) * V[i] + a[i,:])
```